# Discussing $x' = \frac{1}{x+t}-1, x(1) = \xi$ and asymptotic stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

I consider the differential equation

\begin{align} 
x' = \frac{1}{x+t}-1, \quad x(1) = \xi. 
\end{align}

For $\xi > -1$ (and with the help of $y(t) := x(t)+t$) one should find the unique maximal solution $\lambda_{\xi}: I_{\xi} \to \mathbb{R}$. I did that and found

\begin{align}
\lambda_{\xi}(t) = \sqrt{\xi^2 + 2\xi + 2t -1}-t
\end{align}
with $I_{\xi} = \left\{t \in \mathbb{R} \mid t \geq \frac{1-\xi^2-2 \xi}{2}\right\}$.

Now it is asked to show, that $\lambda_0 : I_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ is an asymptotically stable solution of this differential equation. I really don't know how to do that.

**My attempts have been:**

1. Since the differential equation is of the form $x' = f(t,x)$ is would be enough to show that the solution is attractive, which would yield that it is also stable and hence asymptotically stable. But how do I show that the solution is attractive? (I know there is a definition for it but it struggle to apply it)
2. Since the differential equation is of the form $x' = f(t,x)$ I thought about looking at 
   \begin{align}
   y'=f(t, y + \lambda_{\xi}(t))-f(t,\lambda_{\xi}(t))
   \end{align}
   which has the trivial solution $y = 0$ and work from there on.

Would someone mind to show me how to use the definition or more general how to solve the question?

Comment: Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two different solution to the equation. Examine the evolution of $(x_1-x_2)^2$. Differentiating this you should see that $(x_1-x_2)^2 \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: @Mick Do you mean an argument like $\lim_{t \to \infty} ||\lambda_{\xi}(t) - \lambda_0(t)|| = \lim_{t \to \infty} || \sqrt{\xi^2+2\xi+2t-1}-\sqrt{2t-1}|| = 0$?

Comment: yes, along those lines.

Comment: @Mick First of all: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that does not really help. What's the argument you're thinking about? I mean obviously the limit I mentioned in my other comment is $0$. Is that enough to conclude that the solution is attractive and therefore as I explained in my question it is also stable and hence asymptotically stable? That - I mean just saying that the limit is $0$ - seems a bit "hand-waving" to me tbh ... 

Would you mind to help me in a bit more details please?

Comment: Okay, what is the definition of stability and asymptotic stability that you are using?

Comment: @Mick A sol. $\mu : ]-a;\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is called attractive iff $\forall \tau > a \exists \nu > 0$ s.t. for each $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($\xi$ as above) with $||\xi - \mu(t)|| < \nu$ the maximal solution $\lambda(t)$ with $\lambda(\tau) = \xi$ for all $t \geq \tau$ exists and $\lim_{t \to \infty} ||\lambda(t) - \mu(t)|| = 0$. My notes state that showing that the solution is attractive is enough to state that it is asymptotically stable when a ode of the form $x' = f(t,x)$ is considered. There's a bunch of other things that need to be checked according to this def. What def do you use?

Comment: Okay that is the definition of an attractive solution. What is the definition of asymptotic stability? For me, a solution $x:(-a,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ is asymptotically stable if there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any other solution $y$ satisfying $|x(-a)-y(-a)|<\delta$, we have $\lim_t |x(t)-y(t)| = 0$.

Comment: @Mick Ok, thank you. So your $a$ would be - in light of the considered ode and $\xi = 0$ - $\frac12$, correct?. What - in my concrete example - is the "other solution" $y$? Is it $\lambda_{\xi}(t)$?

Comment: The domain of $\lambda_0$ is $(1/2, \infty)$ as you already stated, so $x = \lambda_0$ is the asymptotically stable solution. Any other solution would be $\lambda_\xi$ that is also correct.